# Cannot get output from function

Tags: python

I want calling my function with variable in class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name, jsonItem):
        fDic = {
            'A', self.build_item(jsonItem)
        }

        self.fActive = fDic[name]

    def build_item(self, jsonItem):
         return [jsonItem["name"],jsonItem["property"]]

    def run_function(self):
        self.fActive()
```

main.py :

```
data = A("A", jsonItem)
print data.run_function()
```

When I'm calling this I have :

```
'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Can you explain me ?

Comment: This is not a self-contained and verifiable example. It's also syntactically incorrect. Please provide code that actually produces the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fDic` in `__init__` is a set and you cannot use `[ ]` to access an item in a set.  It seems you intend to use `fDic` as a dictionary.  Your code for `__init__` should then be,

```
def __init__(self, name, jsonItem):
    fDic = {
        'A' : self.build_item(jsonItem)
    }
    self.fActive = fDic[name]
```

In particular, note the `:` after `'A'`.